# No.of zeroes of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Why do polynomial of degree x have x zeroes? I searched on the net but could not find anything.
Is there a derivation or proof?

Comment: Look at the [Factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra

Comment: If you combine the factor theorem and the fundamental theorem of algebra you get the  requested result.

Answer (score 0):

> **Fundamental theorem of algebra (1),**
>
> $ \forall P\in\mathbb{C}[X] ,\deg(P)>0 $ have at least one root in $\mathbb{C}$
>
> **with this second proposition (2)** :
>
> $r \in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of $P$ if and only if $(X-r)|P$

Let $P\in\mathbb{C}[X]$ and $\deg(P)=n$

With the first theorem (1) there exists one root in $\mathbb{C} : z_1$

So $(X-z_1)|P\quad (2) \iff P=(X-z_1)Q_1$

We apply the same method for $Q_1$ $\qquad(\deg(Q_1)=n-1)$

There exists $z_2$....

and by iteration you will find $n$ roots